# TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to run a simple ML classifiers on my data but I am getting below error. I am beginner so kindly explain me the reason aswell when you please provide the solution. thanks
"TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()"

below is my code

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import re  
import nltk 
nltk.download('stopwords')  
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
tweets = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\data.csv")
tweets.shape
```

(4787, 2)

```
 X = tweets.iloc[:, 0].values  
 y = tweets.iloc[:, 1].values

processed_tweets = []

for tweet in range(0, len(X)):  
# Remove all the special characters
processed_tweet = re.sub(r'\W', ' ', str(X[tweet]))

# remove all single characters
processed_tweet = re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', processed_tweet)

# Remove single characters from the start
processed_tweet = re.sub(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', processed_tweet) 

# Substituting multiple spaces with single space
processed_tweet= re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', processed_tweet, flags=re.I)

# Removing prefixed 'b'
processed_tweet = re.sub(r'^b\s+', '', processed_tweet)

# Converting to Lowercase
processed_tweet = processed_tweet.lower()

processed_tweets.append(processed_tweet)


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer  
tfidfconverter = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=2000, min_df=5, max_df=0.7, 
stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))  
X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(processed_tweets).toarray()


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)


X_train.shape
```

(3829, 1710)

```
y_train.shape
```

(3829,)

```
X.shape
```

(4787, 1710)

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
text_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)  
text_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Below is the error which I get when I run above code

---

```
        TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
            <ipython-input-24-7c5c1beb13e6> in <module>()
            1 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
           2 text_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, 
           random_state=0)
           ----> 3 text_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

               C:\miniconda3\envs\conda\lib\site- 
           packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in fit(self, X, y, 
          sample_weight)
            276         self.n_outputs_ = y.shape[1]
              277 
            --> 278         y, expanded_class_weight = 
            self._validate_y_class_weight(y)
           279 
            280         if getattr(y, "dtype", None) != DOUBLE or not 
            y.flags.contiguous:

            C:\miniconda3\envs\conda\lib\site- 
            packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in 
           _validate_y_class_weight(self, y)
             476 
    477     def _validate_y_class_weight(self, y):
--> 478         check_classification_targets(y)
    479 
    480         y = np.copy(y)

C:\miniconda3\envs\conda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    166     y : array-like
    167     """
--> 168     y_type = type_of_target(y)
    169     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    170                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:

C:\miniconda3\envs\conda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in type_of_target(y)
    285         return 'continuous' + suffix
    286 
--> 287     if (len(np.unique(y)) > 2) or (y.ndim >= 2 and len(y[0]) > 1):
    288         return 'multiclass' + suffix  # [1, 2, 3] or [[1., 2., 3]] or [[1, 2]]
    289     else:

<__array_function__ internals> in unique(*args, **kwargs)

C:\miniconda3\envs\conda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
    261     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
    262     if axis is None:
--> 263         ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    264         return _unpack_tuple(ret)
    265 

C:\miniconda3\envs\conda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    309         aux = ar[perm]
    310     else:
--> 311         ar.sort()
    312         aux = ar
    313     mask = np.empty(aux.shape, dtype=np.bool_)

TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()
```

Comment: Anyone guys? Pls help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some values in X_train or y_train are null or 'nan', that's why is trying to compare str() < float(). Check if there are these null values in your data and clean it up.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Should I manually check and remove any empty/nan values? any other way ?

Comment: Looking the error I would say there is no other way because the problem comes after you fit the data into the model, so you cannot check anything in there in order to parse the strings or whatever. Anyways, is a good practice to check the dataset before training any model to see if there is something wrong or something to be cleaned.